# How to make div elements stand in one line, some divs cannot float left

Tags: jquery, html, css, django, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap with django templates, I am populating main content with product elements (divs with different height). Because of the difference in height some divs cannot float properly, I put a screenshot below. How can I fix it. Here is code which generates content:

```
<div class="panel-body">
  <div class="row product-container">

      {% for product in products %}
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
          <div class="product_unit">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/480x400" alt="">
            <div id='quick-view'>
              <a href="#">product.name</a>
            </div>
            <div class="product_unit_desc">
              <h4>{{ product.name }}</h4>
              <div class="ratings">
                <p class>12 reviews</p>
                <p>
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty"></span>
                </p>
              </div>
              <p>$12.43</p>

            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      {% endfor %}

    <!-- DYNAMIC GENERATED CONTENT BY DJANGO -->

  </div> <!-- END OF ROW  -->

</div>
```

[image]

**EDIT**: `float: left;` did not help

Comment: did you try with _row_ class?

Comment: or _pull-left_ class?

Comment: No it did not help, I put pull-left class along with row class, then product_unit class, did not work

Comment: `float: left;` won't work as intended because of the "step-down effect" you're getting with the varying heights of elements. Set a `maximum-height` or `minimum-height`. Alternatively, you could explore `flex-box` solutions.

Comment: @UncaughtTypeError thanks, min-height worked